# Too many output arguments error: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function

I just started with MATLAB and I'm seeking advice for how to make a function work with more arguments.

I've built this formula:

```
I = real((U0.*exp(i.*vw.*vt))./(L.*(-vw.^2+ (R/L).*i.*vw + (1/L.*C)))) + ...
    exp((-R.*vt)./(2.*L).*( alpha.*cos( sD.*vt)+ beta.*sin( sD.*vt)));
```

Therefore I needed the values for `U0`, `vw`, `vt`, `L`, `R`

If I put this in the command window:

```
D = (1/L*C)-((R^.2)/(4*L^.2));
sD = sqrt(D);
vt = linspace(tmin,tmax,200);
vw = omega;
[vw,vt] = meshgrid(vw,vt);
I = real((U0.*exp(i.*vw.*vt))./(L.*(-vw.^2+ (R/L).*i.*vw + (1/L.*C)))) + exp((-R.*vt)./(2.*L).*( alpha.*cos( sD.*vt)+ beta.*sin( sD.*vt)));
surf(vw,vt,I)
```

It works fine.

So, **now I want to create a function which reads the values and calculates all the stuff above and returns a `surf` plot**.

My try:

```
function [u] = test(L,C,R,tmin,tmax,omega,U0)
    D = (1/L*C)-((R^.2)/(4*L^.2));
    sD = sqrt(D);
    vt = linspace(tmin,tmax,200);
    vw = omega;
    [vw,vt] = meshgrid(vw,vt);
    I = real((U0.*exp(i.*vw.*vt))./(L.*(-vw.^2+ (R/L).*i.*vw + (1/L.*C))))+exp((-R.*vt)./(2.*L).*( alpha.*cos( sD.*vt)+ beta.*sin( sD.*vt)));
    surf(vw,vt,I)
end
```

This error occurs:

> Error using alpha
> Too many output arguments.

Do you have an idea how to make this function work?

Answer (score 1):

What is `alpha`? It's likely that it exists in your workspace, so when you call those lines from your workspace everything is fine. However, within the `test` function MATLAB has no visibility of the "base" workspace, and `alpha` doesn't exist! Pass it as an argument or define it like your other values. Ditto with `beta`.

---

Also you have defined the output argument `u` in your function

```
% Ouput  vvv
function [u] = test(L,C,R,tmin,tmax,omega,U0)
```

But you never assigned anything to the variable `u` during the function". If you want to return the `surf` figure object, assign that to `u` when it is called.

```
% Square brackets not needed as only returning one variable
function u = test(L,C,R,tmin,tmax,omega,U0)
   % ... stuff
   u = surf(vw,vt,I)
end
```